# Elastic search turning me different url link other than i uploaded

Tags: elasticsearch, search, search-engine

I am new in Elastic search. I have an array that containes object with name and link properties.I pasted JSON to documents.I can see all my data uploaded correctly, and the links are same. When I go to Search UI and make example search, my links are changing.Here my object that i uploaded.

```
[
    {
        "name": "A. Ekrem Ülkü - Kabala Yahudi Kadim Mistik Öğretisi.epub",
        "link": "https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/56b0b3f2aafbde6d0f041aac2ff1363ba3b63a47de5334dccb440d85f5bc86a0/612909a7/CXKTSAe9XkZn0MDk_8jqeLx91MO3Ivgt_qJhCtsBH8_TwLo4cwyfkzG4HboE4EOQaor6jtYP_cMFa2J63cVoDg%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=A.%20Ekrem%20%C3%9Clk%C3%BC%20-%20Kabala%20Yahudi%20Kadim%20Mistik%20%C3%96%C4%9Fretisi.epub&disposition=attachment&hash=&limit=0&content_type=application%2Fepub%2Bzip&owner_uid=0&fsize=1308729&hid=cce958c27de9b6a29f84810defc32047&media_type=book&tknv=v2&etag=b4c996b8219b7b068f71a233d4264613"
    },
    {
        "name": "A. M. Celal Şengör - Aptalı Tanımak.epub",
        "link": "https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/870a76d0b7bf9de2beea63d1867510e1ef9b6fca8dc80b5c7ce11b0dd0236dd2/612909a7/W9slakyPkEJkyBKiCn-rRuAIT3rb6P8B_2bKZmsfKFtgGumzRETkP-9PYkA1_2fb3G9lH8gmhjxCNTQgEJsP0Q%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=A.%20M.%20Celal%20%C5%9Eeng%C3%B6r%20-%20Aptal%C4%B1%20Tan%C4%B1mak.epub&disposition=attachment&hash=&limit=0&content_type=application%2Fepub%2Bzip&owner_uid=0&fsize=996208&hid=3ae45633fd3f46fc70530b62548e606c&media_type=book&tknv=v2&etag=49ef081b1ffc0fd5a4da4ed5f444e7de"
    }
]
```

When I write **Celal** to search engine, my link turn as **https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk** instead of this [link](http://%22https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/870a76d0b7bf9de2beea63d1867510e1ef9b6fca8dc80b5c7ce11b0dd0236dd2/612909a7/W9slakyPkEJkyBKiCn-rRuAIT3rb6P8B_2bKZmsfKFtgGumzRETkP-9PYkA1_2fb3G9lH8gmhjxCNTQgEJsP0Q%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=A.%20M.%20Celal%20%C5%9Eeng%C3%B6r%20-%20Aptal%C4%B1%20Tan%C4%B1mak.epub&disposition=attachment&hash=&limit=0&content_type=application%2Fepub%2Bzip&owner_uid=0&fsize=996208&hid=3ae45633fd3f46fc70530b62548e606c&media_type=book&tknv=v2&etag=49ef081b1ffc0fd5a4da4ed5f444e7de%22). I didnt understand why elastic search change original link that i added

Comment: can you add the mapping of indice where you put your docs

Comment: @ExploZe i dont understand what you mean by mapping indice?

Comment: elastic indice where you put the data, have a mapping (definition of the data structure) available with GET my_indice/_mapping